# Localhost facebook login not working for lower level of the url

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Thanks in advance for reading.

I've been working with facebook login (both php and javascript sdk methods) for a couple of years and I'm facing a particular problem with new apps I'm developing.

I have an app in my localhost configured as virtual directory as follows:

```
http://localhost/myapp/
```

On facebook, the following settings of my app are pointing to that url: App Domains, Facebook Login Website, App on Facebook (https and http) and Mobile Web.

When I do the login process and point the redirect_uri to `http://localhost/myapp/`, it works fine, the cookie is set and I can make queries to the graph api.

The problem comes when I try to use another redirect uri like `http://localhost/myapp/user_controller/register` (Adds the user to the database). Although it is inside the app url configured on facebook, the SDK outputs an error message (OAuthException | An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. | Code 2500).

I figured out that, to solve this problem for a while, I have to go to the facebook app page: apps.facebook.com/myapp. I have to do it everytime my access_token has expired and, since this app is not intended to be inside facebook, I don't think that this is the best way to solve this.

I hope together we can find a good way to solve this issue and this questions helps future developers.

I'm using CodeIgniter (which I've been using about a year) and Facebook PHP SDK (downloaded directly from the github official repo) as CI library.

Thanks again.

Comment: I should point out that localhost doesn't always behave like all websites. Using a dummy domain like `dev.jesusbet.org` and adding that to your hosts file might give you more reliable results. You don't even need to buy the domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the hosts file with the domain name (www.myapp.com/myapp), but the result was the same.

Actually, it only happens with the redirect_uri. It works fine with others controllers/methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point would you get that error during authentication.

I'm pretty sure that you instead have an error in your code that fails to exchange the `code` for the `access_token` on the `.../register` endpoint, and so you end up using an invalid `access_token`.

Comment: I'm using the php sdk ($facebook->getUser()) to check the user session (like in the example.php of the sdk). Do you think I have to do the access_token exchange manually?.

Thanks in advance!